Want to separate 3 combined strings into individual strings
I cannot separate the result from drive.getList()
I used pyDrive2 to get the name of all folders in the main folder:
foldered_list = drive.ListFile(
    {'q':  "'"+parent_directory_id+"' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file in foldered_list:
    print(file['title'])

and received the result:
my_new_folder
test2
test1

I tried to split them with splitlines() but didn't receive the result I wanted, the result was:
['my_new_folder']
['test2']
['test1']

I tried to use type() and received this:
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>

How can I separate it into 3 individual strings?

Do you want a list containing the three str titles (which usaully is the best approach), or 3 separate strings, say s1, s2, s3?
Both are easy to get:
#1st case
titles_list = [file["title"] for file in foldered_list]
#2nd case
s1, s2, s3 = [file["title"] for file in foldered_list]


Thanks a lot! But can you explain me a little bit about the 2nd case? I dont know why s1 can be the first string

It is called sequence unpacking: if you assign a sequence to exactly as many variables as are the elements in the sequence, Python will assign an element to each variable.
